# Creating and linking a static library to visual basic windows forms application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, sln-file

I have created two programs in Visual Studio2010.

One is a visual basic windows forms application(user frontend) which prompts the user to select a file path (.bin file).
The second program is a Visual Studio C++ Application, which has a **ReadFile() function**, which reads the contents of the binary file and performs some mathematical calculations.

I want to generate a static library(.lib) from the second program and link it with the first program (user frontend).
The user frontend program must be able to pass the file path to the **ReadFile() function** in the static library.

I have created both the programs separately, but finding it difficult to create the static library and link it with the user frontend.
How do i go about this ??

P.S: This may sound as stupid, but my aim is to learn how to create and link a static library to windows forms application.

[The user front end application which prompts the user to select the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMNcC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps To create a static library project:

> 1. On the menu bar, choose File, New, Project.
> 2. In the left pane of the New Project dialog box, expand Installed,
>      Templates, Visual C++, and then select Win32.
> 3. In the center pane, select Win32 Console Application.
> 4. Specify a name for the project—for example, MathFuncsLib—in the Name
>      box. Specify a name for the solution—for example, StaticLibrary—in
>      the Solution Name box. Choose the OK button.
> 5. On the Overview page of the Win32 Application Wizard dialog box,
>      choose the Next button.
> 6. On the Application Settings page, under Application type, select
>      Static library.
> 7. On the Application Settings page, under Additional options, clear
>      the Precompiled header check box.
> 8. Choose the Finish button to create the project.

To create a C++ console app that references the static library

> 1. On the menu bar, choose File, New, Project.
> 2. In the left pane, under Visual C++, select Win32.
> 3. In the center pane, select Win32 Console Application.
> 4. Specify a name for the project—for example, MyExecRefsLib—in the
>      Name box. In the drop-down list next to Solution, select Add to
>      Solution. This adds the new project to the solution that contains
>      the static library. Choose the OK button.
> 5. On the Overview page of the Win32 Application Wizard dialog box,
>      choose the Next button.
> 6. On the Application Settings page, under Application type, select
>      Console application.
> 7. On the Application Settings page, under Additional options, clear
>      the Precompiled header check box.
> 8. Choose the Finish button to create the project.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

You can see additional info in the link above, how to use the code in your project.

**Update following question in comment**:

Right click on your project in the solution explorer and then click on **Properties**.

Next open **Configuration** Properties and then **Linker**.

Now you want to add the folder you have the Allegro libraries in to Additional Library Directories,

Linker -> Input you'll add the actual library files under **Additional Dependencies**.

For the Header Files you'll also want to include their directories under C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories.

Have a copy of your lib file in your main project folder, and done

I hope it supports your question.

Comment: Thanks DeJaVo, Actually you have explained how to build it from scratch. I will try and implement this. However, i already have both the codes and want to link them. Moreover, your second application is not a frontend application, it is a console application. Can i follow similar steps to create a Visual Basic application rather than a VC++ Console application ?? Btw, some points to the question can increase my reputation which can help me like/comment/add screenshots and more links in other threads in the community:-P

Comment: As for your question " Can i follow similar steps to create a Visual Basic application rather than a VC++ Console application" - yes. I added the info in my answer to demonstrate the usage.

Comment: Hi DeJaVo, sorry i couldn't vote up as i have <15 reputation. But i will mark your answer as correct :-) Thank you very much for your effort. I will implement the visual basic part and get back.

Comment: Hi DeJaVo, as suggested by you i created one .lib project and one windows forms application. However i am unable to call the function in the static library code from my windows forms application. How should i proceed ??

Comment: Hi DeJaVo, as you explained, i have build the .lib and linked to an empty project. Both are build without errors. But when i call the static library's function from the empty project, i get LNK2019 and LNK1120 i.e unresolved externals. I double-checked the linking and it looks fine. Why is this happening ??

Comment: Ohh!! adding #pragma comment(lib, "__LibraryName__.lib") in the second project solved it !! Thanks a ton DeJaVo.

Comment: There is nothing in this answer that helps with a Visual Basic WF application.  This will only work with a Visual C++ Windows Desktop application.